# Spring Roo fieldNames4OrderClauseFilter doesn't include parent fields

Tags: spring-roo

Roo's (1.2.5RELEASE) generated `fieldNames4OrderClauseFilter` in `<classname>_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord` doesn't include the names of parent class fields, is this a bug or a feature? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more information... Can you provide an example? Can you test it on 1.3.0 version?

Comment: @jmvivo I'm just back from vacation, let me get caught-up and I'll send you more info.

Comment: Can you try the newer release 1.3.1 RC1?

Comment: I did, same problem. I've uploaded a test case to Jira. https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3570